# What am I? (ft. cool poems)

Tags: wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> Without me,
> There would be no vowel.
> Though consonants would exist,
> The alphabet thrown in the bowel.
> But, now, another problem occurs,
> For bowels exist not,
> When, Death, I am yours.
>
> But, worry not,
> For without me there is no person.
> And surely, nobody would be foolish enough,
> To remove themselves from their thought.

<sup><sup><sup><sup>***What am I?***</sup></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off Rubio, are you

> the letter **E**?

```
Without me,
There would be no vowel.
```

> vowel needs an E

```
Though consonants would exist,
```

> the letter E is not in the word "consonants"

```
The alphabet thrown in the bowel.
```

> The alphabet wouldn't be complete without the E.

```
But, now, another problem occurs,
For bowels exist not,
When, Death, I am yours.
```

> bowels has the letter E, and Death does too.

```
But, worry not,
For without me there is no person.
```

> person also needs an E.

```
And surely, nobody would be foolish enough,
To remove themselves from their thought.
```

> maybe people wouldn't be foolish enough to remove "themselves" from "their thought" because there isn't a string of "themselves" in it?

I don't know what the title means though

Comment: Your fourth spoiler wasn’t changed from Rubio’s, I think...

Comment: Yeah but can you rethink the fourth spoiler before I accept?

Comment: what about now?

Comment: I meant the one under "The alphabet thrown..." This is correct, though, so I'll go ahead and accept anyways...

Answer (score 2):

You are

> the letter **O**.

```
Without me,
There would be no vowel.
```

> v**o**wel needs an O.

```
Though consonants would exist,
```

> **O** is not a consonant, so they're not affected

```
The alphabet thrown in the bowel.
```

> The alphabet wouldn't be complete without the O.

```
But, now, another problem occurs,
For bowels exist not,
When, Death, I am yours.
```

> b**o**wels also need an O.

```
But, worry not,
For without me there is no person.
```

> pers**o**n also needs an O.

```
And surely, nobody would be foolish enough,
To remove me from their thought.
```

> th**o**ught also needs an O.

Also,

> every line in this poem contains at least one **O**.
>  C**oo**l p**o**ems need Os, and this one wouldn't exist without them.

Comment: I didn't think about that last part, nor the second-to-last one... You're sort of thinking on the right lines (+1), but it's not correct...

Comment: Also, I noticed that I had made a small typo, so check the updated poem and try again...